# Understanding pure-virtual functions

Tags: c++, virtual

The following code compiles fine:

```
struct A
{
    const int a;
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct B : A{ };

void A::foo(){ std::cout << "foo" << std::endl; }
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a800590a2d89fe48)

The thing is the struct `A` is an abstract therefore we can't instanciate it. But we can subclass it and

```
struct A
{
    const int a;
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct B : A{ };

void A::foo(){ std::cout << "foo" << std::endl; }

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    B b;
    b.foo(); //error: implement pure-virtual
}
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c7c79276199f1eeb)

still can't use the `A`'s implementation of `foo` and I suspect it will never called. So, I have no idea about application of such definition... Yes, it's useful to provide a definition for a virtual destructors, but that's not the case.

Where the definition of pure-virtuals can be used?

Comment: Is your question "What is this definition useful for?"?

Comment: @immibis that's right.

Answer (score 3):

You can call it explicitly.

```
struct A
{
    const int a;
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

struct B : A
{
    void foo();
};

void A::foo()
{
    std::cout << "A::foo" << std::endl;
}
void B::foo()
{
    A::foo(); // here
    std::cout << "B::foo" << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    B b;
    b.foo(); // prints A::foo followed by B::foo
}
```

Comment: Interesting, so it may look like some default implementation that allows us code reuse, right?

Comment: You can also (buy why would you) do this, and directly call the parent function from the child. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/df8667d840c2a786

Comment: @St.Antario: Which is what I was typing at the time you made your comment :)

Answer (score 2):

You can call it from within `B`. And since `A::foo()` is pure virtual, `B` needs to define foo:

```
struct A {
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};

void A::foo(){ std::cout << "A::foo() ran" << std::endl; }    

struct B : A {
    void foo() {
        A::foo(); // <--
        std::cout << "B::foo() ran" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    B b;
    b.foo();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

But you can (and MUST) implement (if B is to be instantiable) an override for A's `void foo()`.  And THAT implementation CAN (but definitely not required to) call the BASE implementation:

```
struct B : public A
{
    virtual void foo() {A::foo();}
};
```

I HAVE implemented this scenario, where I had a very simple "base" implementation, but required all leafs to ACTIVELY decide to utilize this base (or not) by chaining back to this common implementation.

Comment: Should that `=` be there?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you implement Interfaces in C++. You *force* subclasses to implement that method to be instantiated, and you operate polymorphically in your own code on that abstract base class, leaving the specific implementation to clients of your interface.

As far as the implementing in base class goes, I can only think of two reasons. One, to allow them to not have to special case destructors. And two, B can define its own implementation in terms of A::foo(), IE, a default implementation.

Comment: @St.Antario - if you want to be like that about it - consider the fact that you didn't actually ask a question..